# How can I quickly populate a 100,000x100,000 matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, numpy, matrix

On a matrix of 80000 X 80000 to insert data I am using NumPy:

```
n = 80000
similarity = np.zeros((n, n), dtype='int8')
for i, photo_i in enumerate(photos):
    for j, photo_j in enumerate(photos[i:]):
       similarity[i, j] = score(photo_i, photo_j)
    if i % 100 == 0:
        print(i)
```

This takes too much time. `score` function is O(1). Is there a faster way? I want to plot this matrix as fast as possible but my code has complexity O(n^2). PyTables I want to try but don't know how.

Comment: You might get rid of the loop, you might use only the upper triangle (if your score-function is symmetric), but in it's core: it's a quadratic task and 80k^2 is a lot of work.

Comment: Most probably the time is spent in the `score` function, which you haven't shown; optimizing that would probably lead to better results that trying to optimize the looping code. If you insist, you could replace explicit loops with comprehensions, or get rid of the `i % 100` check and the progress prints. But these will likely be negligible compared to the actual scoring logic.

Comment: @sascha, note the code already only computes the lower triangle (they're doing `for j, photo_j in enumerate(photos[i:])`).

Comment: @Avish the `score` function returns only value "1". Its `O(1)` as I have already in my question.

Comment: Isn't `photos[i:]` making a new copy of that subarray each time it's called?

Comment: @גלעדברקן hmm kind of. But this could be the third loop or not?

Comment: The matrix you're computing has a size of O(n^2), so there's no way to do better than that. The question is do you really need the whole matrix? What's the next step of your algorithm?

Comment: @גלעדברקן the slicing creates a new copy on Python 2, but the OP mentioned this is Python 3 so the slicing only creates a view, which is O(1). Phoenix404, note that on Python 2 you'd have to find some other way to do the slicing, e.g. loop over the indexes and explicitly use photos[j] inside the loop.

Comment: Now that I look at it, I think you have a bug - `enumerate(photos[i:])` will give you the photos at index `i` to `n-1` but enumerate them starting at 0, so you'd get `j=0` for the photo at position `i`, `j=1` for the photo at position `i+1`, etc. So effectively this will iterate over the right triangle of the matrix, but populate the left triangle. Is this what you intended? (this has nothing to do with efficiency).

Answer (score 2):

There's a bunch of different things you could do, which all revolve around avoiding the explicit for-loops, which are slow in Python, and delegating to C-level code (either using Python's underlying C runtime or numpy's builtin array creation methods).

### Using `fromfunction`

Numpy has a built-in function for populating a matrix from a function taking coordinates: [numpy.fromfunction](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html). This might be faster since it does all the iteration and assignment in C instead of Python.

You'd have to supply it a score-by-coordinates function, e.g.:

```py
def similarity_value(i, j, photos=photos):
  return score(photos[i], photos[j])

similarity = numpy.fromfunction(similarity_value, (n, n), dtype='int8')
```

The `photos=photos` in the function definition makes the photos array a local of the function and saves some time accessing it on each invocation; this is a common Python micro-optimization technique.

Note that this computes the similarity for the entire matrix instead of just a triangle. To fix this, you could do:

```py
def similarity_value(i, j, photos=photos):
  return score(photos[i], photos[j]) if i < j else 0

similarity = numpy.fromfunction(similarity_value, (n, n), dtype='int8')
similarity += similarity.T  # fill in other triangle from transposed matrix
```

### Using comprehensions

You could also try creating the similarity matrix from a generator comprehension (or even a list comprehension), again avoiding the explicit for-loops in favor of a comprehension which is faster, but sacrificing the triangle optimization:

```py
similarity = numpy.fromiter((score(photo_i, photo_j) 
                             for photo_i in photos 
                             for photo_j in photos),
                            shape=(n,n), dtype='int8')

# or:
similarity = numpy.array([score(photo_i, photo_j) 
                          for photo_i in photos 
                          for photo_j in photos],
                         shape=(n,n), dtype='int8')
```

To re-introduce the triangle optimization, you could do something like:

```py
similarity = numpy.array([score(photo_i, photo_j) if i < j else 0
                          for i, photo_i in enumerate(photos)
                          for j, photo_j in enumerate(photos)],
                         shape=(n,n), dtype='int8')
similarity += similarity.T
```

### Using `triu_indices` to populate a triangle directly

Finally, you could use `numpy.triu_indices` to assign directly into the matrix's upper (and then lower) triangle:

```py
similarity_values = (score(photo_i, photo_j
                     for photo_i in photos
                     for photo_j in photos[:i])  # only computing values for the triangle
similarity = np.zeroes((n,n), dtype='int8')
xs, ys = np.triu_indices(n, 1)
similarity[xs, ys] = similarity_values
similarity[ys, xs] = similarity_values
similarity[np.diag_indices(n)] = 1  # assuming score(x, x) == 1
```

This approach is inspired by this related question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/107094/create-symmetrical-matrix-from-list-of-values

I don't have a means of benchmarking which of these approaches would work best, but you could experiment and find out. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is very useful information form me.

Comment: I'm interested in finding out which of these approaches, if any, worked best for you.

Comment: I have tried your suggestions but I was getting some errors. For first,  `..fromfunction...` gave me error like: `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` and for list comprehensions the `shape`parameter does not exist.

Comment: I don't have access to NumPy so can't check it myself, but you can look into the `fromfunction` documentation to see how to use it correctly, I certainly could've missed something here. For list comprehensions, you can create a 1-dimensional array from the list and then reshape it, or you can create a 2-dimensional list comprehension as the input for the array (i.e. a list comprehension of rows, each element of which is a list comprehension of column values for that row).